# Direct cast from char int to char in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a following c++ code which needs to convert to c#.

```
char tempMask;

tempMask = 0xff;
```

I am not too sure how to convert this, could some one please let me know what is the use of  below line in c++

```
tempMask = 0xff;
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It initializes `tempMask` with a byte containing value `0xFF`

In C#, you can write

```
tempMask = (char)0xff;
```

or

```
tempMask = Convert.ToChar(0xff);
```

Comment: I am getting a compilation error saying   Constant value '255' cannot be converted to a 'char'

Comment: how do we re-write in to c# ?

Comment: great, it works, problem sorted ,,, but now again I have an another issue with C++ code , this time c++ code used char variable value on else statement to return bool value out of char like below

Comment: else if (tempMask) 
{
 x = 1.00 / 6000.00;
}

Comment: how come in c++ they used char value as bool ?  and how do I convert it to c# ?

Comment: `if(tempMask)` is equivalent to `f(tempMask != '\0')`. For more info [check this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0040__Data-Type/EscapeCharacters.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple initialisation of a variable tempMask in a hexadecimal system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal 
OxFF = 15*16^0+ 15*16^1 = 255 .
In C# you cannot init char with int value without explicit conversion but you can write : char `tempMask = (char)0xFF;`, or if you really want a 8-bit integer - try `byte tempMask = 0xFF;`

Answer (score 0):

A signed char in C/C++ is not a 'char' in C#, it's an 'sbyte' - no cast required:

```
sbyte tempMask;

tempMask = 0xff;
```